# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.example.Address

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, bootstrapping

I'm creating modular application that uses JPA without persistence.xml.
After attempt of using entities I have got

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.example.Address
 at
com.example/com.example.tests.JpaTest.testServiceLoader(JpaTest.java:41)
```

Example implementation I have posted [here](https://github.com/MatthewDruid/hibernate-orm-on-java9-modules/tree/bootstrapping)

What to do to solve that problem?

I have used PersistenceUnitInfo and PersistenceProvider, hibernate have been initialised but when I used one of Entities I got error like in subject. When I used the same application with persistence.xml it have worked. When I used implementation likewise [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bootstrap-jpa) I have got the same error.

main():

```
ServiceLoader<PersistenceProvider> loader = ServiceLoader.load(PersistenceProvider.class);

Optional<PersistenceProvider> optionalProvider = loader.findFirst();

if (optionalProvider.isEmpty()) {
    System.err.println("No javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider found");
    System.exit(-1);
}

PersistenceProvider provider = optionalProvider.get();

EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = provider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(new TestPersistenceUnitInfo(provider.getClass().getName()), new HashMap<String, Object>());

EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

Person person = new Person( 1, "Bob", new Address( 1, "Main Street" ) );
entityManager.persist( person );

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

TestPersistenceUnitInfo()

```
public class TestPersistenceUnitInfo implements PersistenceUnitInfo {

    private static String JPA_VERSION = "2.1";
    private String persistenceUnitName = "testPU";
    private PersistenceUnitTransactionType transactionType = PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL;
    private List<String> managedClassNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> mappingFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Properties properties;
    private DataSource jtaDataSource;
    private DataSource nonjtaDataSource;
    private final List<ClassTransformer> transformers = new ArrayList<ClassTransformer>();
    private String persistenceProviderClassName;

    public TestPersistenceUnitInfo(String provider) {
        this.persistenceProviderClassName = provider;
        this.managedClassNames.add(Address.class.getName());
        this.managedClassNames.add(Person.class.getName());

        this.properties = new Properties();
        //this.properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
        this.properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        //this.properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myDB");
        this.properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql:hojm");
        this.properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "hojm");
    }

    @Override
    public void addTransformer(ClassTransformer arg0) {
        this.transformers.add(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean excludeUnlistedClasses() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
        return Address.class.getClassLoader();
    }

    @Override
    public List<URL> getJarFileUrls() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getJtaDataSource() {
        return this.jtaDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getManagedClassNames() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getMappingFileNames() {
        return this.mappingFileNames;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getNewTempClassLoader() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getNonJtaDataSource() {
        return this.nonjtaDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistenceProviderClassName() {
        return this.persistenceProviderClassName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistenceUnitName() {
        return this.persistenceUnitName;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getPersistenceUnitRootUrl() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPersistenceXMLSchemaVersion() {
        return JPA_VERSION;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        return this.properties;
    }

    @Override
    public SharedCacheMode getSharedCacheMode() {
        return SharedCacheMode.UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    @Override
    public PersistenceUnitTransactionType getTransactionType() {
        return this.transactionType;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
        return ValidationMode.AUTO;
    }
}
```

class Address:

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    Address() {
    }

    public Address(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

class Person:

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Address address;

    Person() {
    }

    public Person(Integer id, String name, Address address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Address` annotated with `@Entity`?

Comment: All entities contain @Entity annotation

Comment: Well, your getManagedClassNames() method returns null... Why do you create a PersistenceUnitInfo implementation? Why don't you use the documented way of bootstrapping JPA? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap

Comment: JB Nizet thank you. Creating PersistenceUnitInfo is suggested in documentation you refer (3.2 JPA Bootstrapping first note). I'm using this approach, because I'm planing to support dynamic changes in connections and want to support ORM